# What is the right way to use polymorphism and inheritance in C++ to handle a basket of fruit?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Say I'm coding a robot that processes a basket of fruit. Oranges need to be juiced, apples need to be sliced, and bananas need to be peeled. Fortunately, *our robot has* the exact tools needed for juicing, slicing, and peeling.

```
Robot::processFruit(List<Fruit*> basket)
{
  foreach(Fruit *fruit, basket)
  {
    if( ? ) { juiceIt(fruit); }
    else if( ? ) { sliceIt(fruit); }
    else if( ? ) { peelIt(fruit); }
  }
}
```

This is a generic example of a problem that I am occasionally confronted with. I have a gut feeling that there is something wrong in my design such that I am even led to a `processFruit()` function, as I'm using an object oriented language, but it doesn't appear to have a clean solution to this problem.

I could create an `enum FruitType { Orange, Apple, Banana}` then require each fruit to implement `virtual FruitType fruitType()`, but then it seems I'm just re-implementing a type system.

Or I could have functions `virtual bool isOrange(); virtual bool isApple(); ...` but as we can see that would get out of hand very quickly.

I could also use C++'s `typeid`, but [this wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/RTTI) says

> RTTI should only be used sparingly in C++ programs.

So I am reluctant to take that approach.

It seems that I must be missing something fundamental and crucial in the design of an object oriented program. C++ is all about inheritance and polymorphism, so is there a better way to approach this problem?

Update: I like the idea of having a generic `process()` function that all `Fruit` are required to implement. But what if I now want to add a `Lemon` and want to juice that? I don't want to duplicate the juicing code, so should I create a `class Juicable : public Fruit` and have Oranges and Lemons both be `Juicable`?

Comment: Please look at "dynamic_cast" [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast] Although having a virtual function to "do_it" would be more elegant than a if-else-if set.

Comment: @Akanksh He specifically says he is "reluctant to take that approach". Look up "double dispatch" and "visitor pattern".

Comment: Yea, `Orange *orange = dynamic_cast<Orange*>(fruit); if(orange) { ... } Apple *apple = ...` I have thought of that as well, but it just seems so messy! That's not how this is meant to be solved in C++ is it?

Comment: There is something wrong with the design. This case normally comes up when you have not `abstracted` correctly, or `inheritance` is not what you really needed.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Yes, you are correct, but he also mentions "typeid" specifically. dynamic_cast is a more common way of doing this. Also, in his case he does not need double dispatch as he is not choosing an implementation based on two polymorphic types, but only one (Fruit) type.

Comment: How about a virtual function in Fruit called "virtual void process()" and then overriding that in Orange, Apple etc. Then calling "fruit->process()" in Robot::process?

Comment: @Akanksh I believe Visitor is the correct pattern here. And either the fruit will know it will be processed by a `Robot`, or it will use a generic visitor interface (which `Robot` will implement), and then you arrive at double dispatch.

Comment: This is a single dispatch, but the dispatch does not belong to the class being dispatched.  Double dispatch solutions could be used mayhap?

Comment: If you are going to have more than one thing that is Juice-able, then yes, you should create an interface which implements the logic for juicing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Tell, don't ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask):

> Procedural code gets information then makes decisions. Object-oriented code tells objects to do things.
>   — Alec Sharp

You want to define a base `Fruit` class, which has a virtual `process` method. Apples, oranges and bananas would each implement their own version of `process` which does the correct thing for that type of fruit. All your robot needs to do is pull the next `Fruit*` out of the basket, and call `process` on it:

```
Robot::processFruit(List<Fruit*> basket)
{
  foreach(Fruit *fruit, basket)
    fruit->process();
}
```

The kind of if/else/else handling you're doing in your code example is exactly the kind of thing that polymorphism is meant to avoid, and it's definitely *not* doing this the "OOP" way.

Comment: fruit should not logically be aware of how to process it, the robot should test the fruit to see what to do with it..

Comment: I have thought of this as well, the usual problem I encounter is that my `Robot` has the tools needed to process the fruit, and so when I later want to juice a lemon, I want to reuse those tools. So at that point do I start creating "class Juicable : public Fruit" and "class Orange : public Juicable"? That still seems unclean, but I'm not sure, is it correct?

Comment: @DoryZidon No, absolutely not. This is completely wrong-headed. You're going to define an ever-growing if/else/else/else/else for each type of fruit in the world, that is **not** OOP. An if/else with hundreds of branches is the exact wrong way to write this code. At that point, you should be using structs.

Comment: @meagar if else if else is horrible..what you want is to use interfaces..a Fruit has a certain property...ie it is squeezable, juiceable, peelable, etc..then you can render certain operations on it. That would be the correct logical design IMO.. I would not have a lemon peel itself..You could add a wrapper around lemon -> LemonProcessor, then have an abstract base class FruitProcessor, then have the process method..But never add it directly to the Lemon..that would be too strange IMO.

Comment: @DoryZidon Now you're shoe-horning in layers of abstraction just to avoid something that is "weird", in an example that is already *extremely* contrived. I can't get to seriously invested in a debate on the architecture of a fruit basket. I will say that I think strict adherence to the notion that your objects *must* reflect the way things work in the physical world does a huge disservice to OOP, and can yield grossly overcomplex architectures for no real benefit.

Comment: @DoryZidon There's no discernible difference between peeling, juicing or squeezing from the robot's perspective, so the operation should have the same name. The implementation of the robot's "process" function for each fruit differs, but there's no point in exposing that - there's no logical "squeeze" function on a banana. Having a "process" function on "fruit" is logical, as well as making it slice a banana.

Comment: @meagar: What Dory suggests is absolutely not wrong-headed, and is absolutely correct OOP-wise.  There are infinite things that can be done to a fruit by various objects.  *"What a robot should do to me in order to prepare me for human consumption"* should absolutely *not* be part a fruit's funcionality.  That is quite logically the robot's job to determine.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I disagree. Encapsulating this logic inside the fruit is by far and away the easiest and cleanest way of implementing this, and the purest in terms of actual adherence to OOP tenants. I really don't care that in "real life" fruits don't know how to process themselves. As I say, this is an extremely contrived example and I really can't be asked to argue further.

Comment: @meagar I am not shoe-horning IMO. Just designing a system that makes sense. More importantly it's exactly what the author is looking for: the Robot has to use a certain tool on a fruit to get the job done, and wishes to reuse the tool..The tool makes absolute sense to be a juicer, a peeler, etc hence the robot doesn't care about the fruit, but cares about which operations it can do with the fruit...you could change the class name to SelfProcessedFruit and use composition to wrap around a fruit (like share_ptr) but I know that weird designs makes complex machines impossible to maintain...

Comment: Sounds like this conversation needs to continue in the chat.

Comment: We use OOP to enhance reusability and extensiblity sort of things, but not for exact duplicate what the world is. There should be software engineering benefits to design class in a specific way.

Comment: More importantly, you don't want mega `Fruit` classes.  We have a task (preparing food), and the code to do that should be encapsulated in the `FoodPrepRobot` class, along side code for preparing `Meat` and `Veggies`, because scattering that code all over the code base in each particular `Fruit` type seems like a maintenance nightmare.  At the same time, `dynamic_cast`-switch style code is also a nightmare to maintain, because when a new `Fruit` is added some code somewhere silently fails.

Answer (score 3):

The way I would handle this situation is to create a superclass called Fruit with a pure virtual method called process(). Orange, Apple and Banana will all superclass fruit, and each of them will provide an implementation of process() which takes the appropriate action for that particular type (i.e., subclass) of fruit.

So your loop would look more like:

```
Robot::processFruit(List<Fruit *> basket)
{
    foreach(Fruit *fruit : basket)
    {
        fruit->process();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, Robot's function would basically need a way to determine the type of fruit it's dealing with. Typically when I need to do this, I simply try to dynamic_cast<>() the Fruit pointer to whatever other type it might be. For instance, suppose I have a Fruit * to an object that is a Banana. I would take advantage of the following:

```
Fruit *f = new Banana();
Orange *o = dynamic_cast<Orange *>(f); // o is NULL, since f is NOT an Orange.
Banana *b = dynamic_cast<Banana *>(f); // b points to the same object as f now.
```

However, the first solution is, in my opinion, far cleaner and more respectful of object oriented programming. The second solution is sometimes useful, but should be used sparingly.

Update: If you really want the Robot to do the processing code, then I would suggest, instead of having the Robot call process(), have your robot class implement the processing methods, and then have the fruit itself take advantage of the robot - e.g.:

```
Robot::juiceIt(Orange *o)
{
    // ...
}

Robot::sliceIt(Apple *a)
{
    // ...
}

Robot::peelIt(Banana *b)
{
    // ...
}

Orange::process(Robot *r)
{
    r->juiceIt(this);
}

Apple::process(Robot *r)
{
    r->sliceIt(this);
}

Banana::process(Robot *r)
{
    r->peelIt(this);
}
```

Comment: This looks much better, and if you combine this with my answer, i think that would be the way to handle it..but as I said before you can also add a wrapper around lemon called lemonProcessor.

Comment: So close. `for(Fruit *fruit : basket)` makes it actual functioning C++ (11).

Comment: I would still probably recommend the first solution over the second, if only because it makes the code cleaner. I consider more concise code to be more important than making sure the way my objects behave lines up with their real-life counterparts. However, the "robot implements processing code" solution is not at all bad, just maybe a bit more verbose.

Comment: The only thing is that the methods are not reusable on the robot, so as other posters in other answers have suggested it might be better to use a "Juiceable" interface so that the `Robot::juiceIt(Orange *o)` becomes `Robot::juiceIt(Juiceable *o)` and then whatever fruit needs to be juiced can be by inheriting that interface...

Comment: @Caribou this is exactly why the first solution should be used, where the fruits implement the logic for process(). Creating an overly complex system of interfaces makes it line up more with reality, but at the same time makes the code way longer and more convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

I think @meagar has the better solution but I want to put this out there.

```
Robot::processFruit(List<Fruit*> basket)
{
    foreach(Fruit *fruit, basket)
        fruit->process(*this);
}

Orange::process(Robot & robot) {
    robot.JuiceIt(*this);
}
```

This solution say a fruit needs a robot to process it.

Answer (score 1):

If I really, really needed to solve this problem and I couldn't engineer my way around it...  I'd write a type-aware double dispatch processor, and use it as a single-dispatch on the argument type only.

First, write a `functions` class that is a type erased function overload set.  (This isn't trivial!)

```
typedef functions< void(Apple*), void(Orange*), void(Banana*) > processors;
```

Second, maintain a set of `FruitTypes` in a compile time list:

```
type_list< Apple, Orange, Banana > CanonincalFruitTypes;
typedef functions< void(Apple*), void(Orange*), void(Banana*) > FruitProcessor;
```

this has to be maintained somewhere.  The relationship between these two lists can be automatic with a bit of work (so `FruitProcessors` is produced from `CanonicalFruitTypes`)

Next, write a reflection style dispatch:

```
class Fruit {
public:
  virtual void typed_dispatch( FruitProcessor ) = 0;
  virtual void typed_dispatch( FruitProcessor ) const = 0;
};
template<typename Derived>
class FruitImpl: public Fruit {
  static_assert( std::is_base< Derived, FruitImpl<Derived> >::value, "bad CRTP" );
  static_assert( /* Derived is in the Fruit type list */, "add fruit type to fruit list" );
  Derived* self() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
  Derived const* self() const { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
  virtual void typed_dispatch( FruitProcessor f ) final overrode {
    f(self());
  }
  virtual void typed_dispatch( FruitProcessor f ) const final overrode {
    f(self());
  }
};
```

Use tricks to make deriving from `Fruit` not through a `FruitImpl` illegal (`friend` and `private` based stuff).

then, the Robot can go to town:

```
void Robot::process( Fruit* fruit ) {
  fruit->typed_dispatch( MyHelperFunctor(this) );
}
```

where `MyHelperFunctor` returns a functor with overrides for the various types of `Fruit` the `Robot` can handle, and `functions<...>` has to be smart enough to test that each signature it supports can be handled by the passed in functor (this is the non-trivial part) and do proper dispatch to them.

If someone derived from `Fruit`, they do it via `FruitImpl`, which enforces it being in the fruit list.  When the fruit list changes, the `typed_dispatch` signature changes, which requires that all users of it implement an override that can accept every fruit type in the list.

This allows you to decouple the `virtual` behavior of `Fruit` when processed by a `Robot` from the `Fruit` implementation itself, while enforcing compile-time checks that all types are handled.  If their is a hierarchy of `Fruit`, the `Robot`'s helper functor can make compile-time decisions to dispatch the call based on that heirarchy (which is translated into a run-time decision in `functions`).  The overhead is an extra `virtual` function call (for the type-erased `functions`), and the construction of the type-erased `functions` object.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a text book case for the [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern. In the sample below I'm not using the standard visitor pattern class or function names, rather I'm using names that are relevant to the domain in this case - i.e. `FruitProcessor` and `Process`, rather than `Visitor` and `Apply`. I'm not going to comment much further as I think the code is pretty self explanatory other than to mention that this design requires the FruitProcessor to be manually updated when adding more types of fruit. There are various ways to handle that including registering fruit processing handlers or even using an abstract fruit processing factory (see [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) for more details). I would like to mention that there is another way that definitely requires a look and that was presented at boostcon by Sean Parent: see it on Youtube: [Value Semantics and concept based polymorphism](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BpMYeUFXv8)

```
class Apple;
class Orange;

class FruitProcessor
{
public:
    virtual void Process(Apple& apple) = 0;
    virtual void Process(Orange& orange) = 0;
};

class Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void Process(FruitProcessor& proc) = 0;
};


class Apple : public Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void Process(FruitProcessor& proc) override
    {
        proc.Process(*this);
    }
};

class Orange : public Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void Process(FruitProcessor& proc) override
    {
        proc.Process(*this);
    }
};

class RobotFruitProcessor : public FruitProcessor
{
public:
    virtual void Process(Apple& apple) override
    {
        std::cout << "Peel Apple\n";
    }
    virtual void Process(Orange& orange) override
    {
        std::cout << "Juice Orange\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Fruit*> fruit_basket;

    fruit_basket.push_back(new Apple());
    fruit_basket.push_back(new Orange());

    RobotFruitProcessor rfp;

    for(auto f : fruit_basket)
    {
        f->Process(rfp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```